# searching for list of vowels and replacing the vowels with dot (.) in a given string in scala

Tags: scala

The program was supposed to do the following in Scala : in the given string, consisting if uppercase and lowercase letters, it:
deletes all the vowels and
replaces a character "." and
replaces all uppercase consonants with corresponding lowercase ones.
I need this solution in Scala programming only.

Comment: can you post some sample & expected output ?

Comment: Sample input : BangaLore
Sample output : b.ng.l.r.

Comment: If you post your attempt so far, we can help with any problems you are having, but this is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> val vowels= Set('a','e','i','o','u') // List Of vowels
oval: Seq[Char] = List(a, e, i, o, u)

scala> val data = "BangaLore" // Value
data: String = BangaLore

scala> data.toLowerCase.map(c => if(vowels(c)) '.' else c)
res17: String = b.ng.l.r.
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas, I'm getting error as type mismatch without mkString

Comment: can you post your code in question ??

Comment: change this ```"."```  to ```'.'```, it will work.

Comment: I used 'Seq' instead of 'Set' while declaring vowels. When I change it to Set its working fne